# How to know if an EEPROM IC can interface via Octospi?

Tags: spi, eeprom

I just learned that Octospi can NOT be configured to be used as a standard SPI device as Octospi was designed to be used to interface with external memory devices.

The thing is, EEPROM ICs don't seem to advertise if the chip can interface with Octospi or not. Is there a way to tell?

As an example, I want to interface to CAT25512HU5I-GT3 by OnSemi. My team has interfaced with this device using standard SPI, but could Octospi be used since it is external memory? If not, any help finding a replacement would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which device it is? If an MCU please give exact model, because, it depends on the exact model. OctoSpi may just be a fancy trademark name for a SPI bus with 8 data wires, the controller may allow using less wires, but it all boils down to what datasheet says the MCU is capable of.

Comment: What is OctoSPI? Are you referring to the protocol? An EEPROM? Or a peripheral on an MCU?

Comment: I am programing the STM32L4S9AII6 by ST.

Comment: OctoSPI is a protocol. It is fairly new.

Comment: So you have read the MCU datasheet and reference manual about Octospi peripheral?

Comment: But what are YOU referring to in your question when you simply say "OctoSPI"? Are you referring to the peripheral or the EEPROM? Because your title seems to be asking about the EEPROM but your first sentence seems to be asking about the peripheral. Because an EEPROM manufacturer certainly will advertise if an EEPROM supports OctoSPI just like they do with QuadSPI. If that's the question then the problem might be it's an EEPROM and not flash. So I am not sure if that is what you're asking or if you're asking whether you can configure the OctoSPI on an MCU to behave as a normal SPI.

Comment: DKNguyen, I can see that you are understanding my question now.

Comment: OctoSPI is not a protocol but configurable module inside MCU.

Comment: Okay so it seems my first assumption that Octospi CAN be used as a traditional SPI may still be correct. I am reading conflicting information on this. I am going to hook it up in the lab and see it for myself. However, unlike with SPI, ST does not have HAL API functions that allow you to transmit & receive simultaneously. The OctoSPI HAL library lacks this type of API call. Let me experiment some more and I'll check back.

Comment: Yes, that is not surprising. Many QuadSPI slaves don't initially respond to QuadSPI on power-up. You have to tell them to turn on QuadSPI through regular SPI,. Usually shares the same pins as a regular SPI peripheral anyways even if the module itself doesn't support it.

Comment: But why would you want to read and write simultaneously? That makes no sense, for a standard SPI Flash, you transfer the opcode to read data and from which address to chip, and then you transfer data back from the chip. Also the point of Octospi interface is that you can memory map the SPI Flash. Not sure how much it makes sense to memory map a standard SPI device due to low bandwidth though.

Answer (score 2):

Quote from STM32 application note on Octospi (https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an5050-octospi-interface-on-stm32-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

"The OCTOSPI provides a flexible hardware interface, that enables the support of multiple
hardware configurations: Single-SPI (traditional SPI), Dual-SPI, Quad-SPI, Dual-quad-SPI
and Octo-SPI"

Comment: So the octoSPI is not a protocol but configurable module in MCU. @michae

Answer (score 0):

To find out if your EEPROM chip supports octoSPI, go to its datasheet and count the number of data pins used for the SPI connection. If there's 8 then it can do octospi, if theres 4 it can do quadspi. Quad and OctoSPI are usually "half-duplex" which means the same set of pins are used to send and receive data and only one of these operations can happen at once. Normal SPI (transmit only 1 bit at a time) is usually full-duplex which means it has separate wires for sending and receiving, and can do both at the same time. It has 2 wires for that, called SI and SO for "Serial in" and "serial out".

I would not recommend octoSPI, as Ive not seen many EEPROM parts with the correct pin arrangement. I would either use QuadSPI chip, or if you really need speed, use the Flexible External Memory Controller on your STM32 with a proper address and data bus.

If your EEPROM is only 64KB, you probably will not need anything faster than normal SPI as it would take approximately 25ms to completely read the whole EEPROM (512Kb/20MHz = 25ms)